# How to reverse the scroll on page which loads at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is  one page site which loads at the bottom.  I would like to reverse the scroll so that the user can naturally scroll down to move through the content but have the downwards scroll move up through page content.

Comment: Are you looking for "back to top button" that appears at the bottom of the page?

Comment: no, basically it is a site for kids where a rocket ship will blast off at the bottom of the page and travel to upwards to the moon as they scroll. I've got the page loading at the bottom, but I would like to somehow reverse the scroll, so scrolling down would actually move you up in the page.